# Explicit proof of the fact that a non integrally closed domain is not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

**Context.** Let $R$ be a domain. It is well-known that $R$ is a PID $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is a UFD $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is integrally closed (in its field of fractions).

In other words, we have $R$ is not integrally closed $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is not a UFD $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is not a PID.

The implication $R$ is not integrally closed $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is not a PID may be made explicit as follows: let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$, and let $\dfrac{a}{s}\in K\setminus R$ which is integral over $R$. Then one may show that the ideal $(a,s)$ of $R$ is not a principal ideal.

**Question.**  In the same spirit as before, can we make the implication $R$ is not integrally closed $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is not a UFD explicit ? In other words, can we produce a nonzero element of $R$ which either does not have any decomposition into irreducibles, or which has at least two distincts decompositions ?

**Remark.** Keeping notation above, I thought at first that $a$ or $s$ would be suitable candidates. Unfortunately, it does not work. For example, consider $R=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha=\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{19}}{2}$.
Then $\alpha$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, hence over $R$, but does not lie in $R$. However, $-1+i\sqrt{19}$ and $2$ are both irreducible in $R$ and have a unique decompostion into irreducibles (it comes from the fact that the equation $\vert \pi\vert^2=4$ or $20$ do not have a lot of solutions).
Nevertheless, we see that $80=2^4\cdot 5=2^2(1+i\sqrt{19})(1-i\sqrt{19})$ has two distinct decompositions into irreducibles. However, I do not see how we could generalize this to an arbitrary $R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{a}{b} \in K \setminus R$ be integral over $R$: $$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n + r_{n-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n-1} + \cdots + r_0 = 0 \tag{*}$$
Multiplying through by $b^n$ and rearranging:
$${a}^n = -b(r_{n-1}a_{n-1} + \cdots + r_0b^{n-1})$$

If $b$ is irreducible, then we're done. Indeed, $b$ doesn't divide $a$ (because $\frac{a}{b} \notin R$), so if we decompose $a$ into irreducibles, this decomposition can't contain $b$, hence we can form a decomposition of $a^n$ that doesn't contain $b$.
So we've found two distinct factorizations of the same element of $R$.

Now suppose $b$ is not irreducible.
If $b$ cannot be written as *any* (finite) product of irreducibles (e.g. in some cases if $R$ is not Noetherian), then $R$ is automatically not a UFD, because this is one of the two defining conditions.
If instead we *can* write it as a finite product of irreducibles, in particular we can write $b = \pi b'$ where $\pi$ is irreducible.
Multiply (*) by $(b')^n$ to show that $x' = \frac{a}{\pi}$ is integral over $R$.
Moreover, we can assume $x'$ is not in $R$, because we can assume $a$ and $b$ are coprime (if not, simplify).
Now apply the previous case.

---

In your example, we get the following two factorizations of $-18 - 2\sqrt{-19}$ by applying the procedure above, using the fact that the minimal polynomial of $\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}$ is $x^2 + x + 5$:
$$ (-1 + \sqrt{-19})^2 = -2(9 + \sqrt{-19})$$
Regardless of whether $9 + \sqrt{-19}$ is irreducible or it can be reduced further into a product of irreducibles, this will lead to distinct factorizations because $2$ is irreducible and will appear in the RHS factorization but not in the LHS factorization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that there is some gap though? How do you ensure that we can assume that $a$ and $b$ are coprime ? I think I can fill it . If $a$ or $b$ does not have unique decomposition, we are done. Assume they do, and set $d=\prod_\pi \pi^{\min(v_\pi(a),\min(v_\pi)},$ where $\pi$ describes a set of represnetative of irreducible elements. Write $a=da'$ and $b=db'$. If $a'$ or $b'$ does not have unique decomposition, we are done. Other wise, comparing powers shows that $a'$ and $b'$ do not have any common irreducible factor.

Comment: To deduce they are coprime, let $d'$ be a common divisor of $a'$ and $b'$. If $d'$ is not a unit, then either $d'$ has no decomposition , and we are done, or one may find an irreducible divising $d'$ and we can conclude. Howver, this seems overcomplicated. Is there a simpler argument that I did not see ?

Comment: Indeed I was a bit slopping when saying "we can assume $a$ and $b$ are coprime". As we're not in a UFD, the notion of coprime is not precise. But we just need a very simple statement: if $b = \pi b'$, then we can assume $\pi$ doesn't divide $a$, in the sense that $a$ is not $\pi a'$. If it were the case, we just eliminate $\pi$ from numerator and denominator in the fraction $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{\pi a'}{\pi b'} = \frac{a'}{b'}$ and start over. This process must terminate at some point because there can only be finitely many irreducible factors in a product.